# Simple and fast way to show interactive functions associated with a package

Tags: commands

I am using `M-x protoc` to show me the interactive functions provided by the package `protoc`.  Is it possible to have a shortcut for displaying `protoc` related functions without having to write `protoc TAB` after calling `M-x`?

For instance, the following fails

```
(global-set-key (kbd "H-x") (kbd "M-x protoc"))
```

Comment: Since I have taken you to task often about your questions, I wanted to acknowledge that this was a good one: interesting in itself plus it gave rise to a couple of enlightening answers and  a couple of links to even more  questions/answers that were equally interesting and enlightening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT better alternative

A better alternative, provided in Emacs since version 28,
is to use the `read-extended-command-predicate` to (pre-)filter the candidates listed by `M-x`:

```lisp
(defun execute-my-extended-command (&optional prefixarg)
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((read-extended-command-predicate
         (lambda (s _)
           (string-match "protoc" (symbol-name s)))))
    (execute-extended-command prefixarg)))
```

I'll keep the old answer below, as it is also informative.

END EDIT

I don't understand `unread-command-events` very well, but from the answer [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/57935/26163), I figured that you could use

```lisp
(defun execute-my-extended-command (&rest args)
  "Read a command name to call, favoring commands that begin with `*'.

Like `execute-extended-command', but when called interactively, preload a
leading `*' into the minibuffer."
  (interactive)
  (if (interactive-p)
      (progn
        (setq unread-command-events (listify-key-sequence "protoc"))
        (call-interactively #'execute-extended-command))
    (funcall #'execute-extended-command args)))
```

Now you could bind that command to `H-x` (Wow, you have a hyper key!)

Answer (score 1):

There is no association between functions (or variables) and the packages they were defined in, nor are packages even first–class objects. There is just the global environment and whatever functions (and variables) that have been defined therein.

However, by convention one names the functions and variables defined in a package with a prefix that contains or is at least similar to the package name, so all you have to do is enumerate the list of known symbols using `mapatoms`, searching for those that are `fboundp` and have the prefix you are looking for.

See [chapter 9.3 Creating and Interning Symbols](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Symbols.html) as well as the function documentation for `mapatoms` and `fboundp` for more information.

Comment: Could you provide some example on how they can be used for the task?

Comment: @db48x See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/71691/list-definitions-for-a-package